# Location of Heroku SSL certs when using Automated Cert Management

Tags: heroku

I need to provide the public / private keys off the ssl cert to an application - what is the "path" to them on heroku when using automated certificate management?

(I am guessing this is the same path that would be used with  `heroku certs:chain`)

Answer (score 1):

Answer courtesy of Heroku themselves - thanks guys!

> The SSL certificate and key are not stored in a path accessible on the Dyno. SSL termination happens as part of the frontend routing fleet, the unencrypted contents are then routed to your application internally. If you need them as part of your application, you will either have to add them as files to your application's source code, or I've also seen individuals add them as configuration variables.